# Why does this inner function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, function

I do this

```
function myFunction() {
    var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    function getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }
}

var myProperty = myFunction;
myProperty.getMyVar();  // tells me myProperty.getMyVar is not a function.
```

and

```
function myFunction() {
    var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    function getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }
}

var myProperty = myFunction();
myProperty.getMyVar();   // tells me myProperty is undefined
```

and even

```
function MyFunction() {
    var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    function getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }
}

var myProperty = new MyFunction();
myProperty.getMyVar();  // tells me myProperty.getMyVar is not a function.
```

and in all three cases I get problems.  I have included the problem as in line comment in all three sections.  Now, before someone tells me to just use a closure, I am not trying to understand closures, I am trying to understand exactly what happens with inner functions.

If you can explain above, I would grateful. Because it is counter intuitive to me.

Thanks

Comment: Inner functions are not *properties* of the enclosing function.

Answer (score 5):

What you did is just define a function inside `myFunction`, creating a closure ...

To remedy the implementation, make `getMyVar` an ***instance member***:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    this.getMyVar = function () {
        return myVar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Excuse my pedantry but this also creatse a closure because it is also defining a function inside myFunction - albeit an anonymous one.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't exposing the getMyVar function.

You want:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    this.getMyVar = function() {
        return myVar;
    }
}
```

However, myVar is also locally scoped to the function execution... and the funciton hasn't been executed.

The last lines need to be

```
(new myFunction()).getMyVar();
```

EDIT: Though perhaps all you're looking for is pseudo-namespacing? In which case you can do:

```
var myObject = { 
    myProperty: "value",
    myFunction: function() { }
}
```

Or, more likely you're trying to make myVar act like a private member, in which case you can do:

```
var myObject = function() {
    var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    return { 
        getMyVar: function() {
            return myVar;
        }
    }
}(); //self-executing function
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have a further question on encapsulation. Might take that in a separate thread.